# Highcharts Graph Blank Using JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am new to using HighCharts and JSON.  I am pulling data from my database and it is producing the following JSON:

```
{"GS10":[{"data_date":-528656400,"value":2.83},{"data_date":-526064400,"value":3.05},{"data_date":-523386000,"value":3.11},{"data_date":-520794000,"value":2.93},{"data_date":-518115600,"value":2.95},{"data_date":-515437200,"value":2.87},{"data_date":-512845200,"value":2.66},{"data_date":-510166800,"value":2.68},{"data_date":-507574800,"value":2.59},{"data_date":-504896400,"value":2.48},{"data_date":-502218000,"value":2.47},{"data_date":-499798800,"value":2.37},{"data_date":-497120400,"value":2.29},{"data_date":-494528400,"value":2.37},{"data_date":-491850000,"value":2.38},{"data_date":-489258000,"value":2.3},{"data_date":-486579600,"value":2.36},{"data_date":-483901200,"value":2.38}]}
```

This JSON is then to be rendered into a line chart using HighCharts.  The script is below.  It renders a graph, but the graph is blank.  I am currently only testing with one series, but the intent is to be able to use multiple series once I can successfully graph one.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<script>
$(function () {
var test_point = 'GS10';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json) {
    var seriesArr = [];
    var series = {
        name: test_point,
            data: []
        };
        $.each(json[test_point], function(key, data){
                series.data.push({
                    date: data.data_date,
                    value: data.value
                });

    });
    seriesArr.push(series);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
            },
        series: seriesArr
        };
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with that part:

```
            series.data.push({
                date: data.data_date,
                value: data.value
            });
```

It shouldn't be `data`/`value` but rather `x`/`y`:

```
            series.data.push({
                x: data.data_date,
                y: data.value
            });
```